# How to include local jars into a fat jar using Gradle 6.3?

Tags: java, gradle, executable-jar

On a Linux machine running Java 8 and Gradle 6.3 I need to build a fat jar made of mix of libraries, some sourced from Maven Central, others from a local `libs` directory located at the root of my repository, together with my `build.gradle` and the `gradlew`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

After running `./gradlew clean build` and `cd build/libs`, if I `unzip myproject.jar` I can see that no dependencies have been included in the jar.

My end goal is to make my project executable as `java -jar myproject.jar`.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a `build.gradle` that generates a fat jar including local dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

group 'com.mycompany.foo'
version '1.0'

jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'myjarname'
    archiveVersion = '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.mycompany.foo.Main'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.20.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After unzipping your jar file check here for all dependencies.

```
Your-Project --> BOOT-INF --> libs

by default, if your Gradle build is successful the jar files come here.
```

you can run java -jar then.

Comment: I have a `META-INF/` containing only a MANIFEST.FM.